# It is possible to unregister a ros-service?

Tags: ros, rosservice, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to dispose the register resources when an specific node dies. I'm aware that parameters can be deleted. But, it is possible to do the same with services?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47366/it-is-possible-to-unregister-a-ros-service?/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2012-11-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**rospy**

You can unregister a service by calling `shutdown()` on the `rospy.Service` object ([doc here](http://ros.org/rosdoclite/groovy/api/rospy/html/rospy.impl.tcpros_service.Service-class.html)). It looks like this isn't done automatically on destruction like in the ros c++ implementation. Maybe it should do that.

**roscpp**

Are you seeing a service persist even after it's been destroyed? The way to unregister  a service manually is to call `shutdown()` on the `ServiceServer` object ([doc here](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1ServiceServer.html#a080073670c5010c6c293a204f3234e7a)), but this should happen automatically when the `ServiceServer` object is destroyed. Maybe you're not actually destroying the server object.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2012-11-03**:
Nice! It worked! :-)

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2017-10-13**:
The link to the rospy documentation is dead. It can be found [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/rospy/html/rospy.impl.tcpros_service.Service-class.html).